# Same or more powerfull as highlight-symbol?

Tags: highlighting

Windows 10, Emacs 25.

I use package **highlight-symbol** for highlighting text. It's very useful.

But after 3 years of using it was not enough for me.

Is Emacs has another package with same or more powerfull capabilities?

Comment: What capabilities are you looking for? You aren't asking for anything specific, so it's hard to tell what you need.

Comment: I want to compare with another "highlight" packages. Maybe another package has more capabilities. Please give me a list of this kind of packages. Thanks.

Comment: Tell us *why* "it was not enough for [you]". What did you want to do that it couldn't do? There's no point in people making suggestions if they won't solve your problem.

Comment: I need more colors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment by @DoMinNeLa suggests, your question as written is too broad, so it risks being closed. Please consider specifying one or more particular kinds of highlighting behavior you are looking for.

That said, here are a couple of libraries you can use to highlight symbols. They offer similar features to what `highlight-symbol.el offers`, but also other features.

- [Highlight Lisp Functions](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLispFunctions) (library [`hl-defined.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/hl-defined.el))

  Highlight symbols that are known to be defined functions and/or variables in an Emacs-Lisp buffer. Or you can highlight symbols that are not known to be defined functions or variables.
- Library [Highlight](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/HighlightLibrary) ([`highlight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el))

  General highlighting features.

Comment: I need more colors for highlight.

Comment: What does that mean, specifically. You can use any number of colors and any number of faces. You are not *specifying* your need/question -- You are not using specific terms.